# Using Python v3.5 to load a tab-delimited file, omit some rows, and output max and min floating numbers in a specific column to a new file

Tags: python, csv, header, output, floating

I've tried for several hours to research this, but every possible solution hasn't suited my particular needs.
I have written the following in Python (v3.5) to download a tab-delimited .txt file.

```
#!/usr/bin/env /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin/python3.5
import urllib.request
import time
timestr = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
filename="/data examples/"+ "ace-magnetometer-" + timestr + '.txt'
urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/ace-magnetometer.txt', filename=filename)
```

This downloads [the file from here](http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/ace-magnetometer.txt) and renames it based on the current time. It works perfectly.

I am hoping that I can then use the "filename" variable to then load the file and do some things to it (rather than having to write out the full file path and file name, because my ultimate goal is to do the following to several hundred different files, so using a variable will be easier in the long run).

This using-the-variable idea seems to work, because adding the following to the above prints the contents of the file to STDOUT... (so it's able to find the file without any issues):

```
import csv
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, dialect='excel', delimiter='\t')
    for row in reader:
            print(row)
```

As you can see from [the file](http://services.swpc.noaa.gov/text/ace-magnetometer.txt), the first 18 lines are informational. 
Line 19 provides the actual column names. Then there is a line of dashes.

The actual data I'm interested in starts on line 21.

I want to find the minimum and maximum numbers in the "Bt" column (third column from the right). One of the possible solutions I found would only work with integers, and this dataset has floating numbers.

Another possible solution involved importing the pyexcel module, but I can't seem to install that correctly...

```
import pyexcel as pe
data = pe.load(filename, name_columns_by_row=19)
min(data.column["Bt"])
```

I'd like to be able to print the minimum Bt and maximum Bt values into two separate files called minBt.txt and maxBt.txt.

I would appreciate any pointers anyone may have, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will work as long as all the files are formatted in the same way, i.e. data 21 lines in, same number of columns and so on. Also, the file that you linked did not appear to be tab delimited, and thus I've simply used the string `split` method on each row instead of the csv reader. The column is read from the file into a list, and that list is used to calculate the maximum and minimum values:

```
from itertools import islice

# Line that data starts from, zero-indexed.
START_LINE = 20
# The column containing the data in question, zero-indexed.
DATA_COL = 10
# The value present when a measurement failed.
FAILED_MEASUREMENT = '-999.9'

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:

    bt_values = []

    for val in (row.split()[DATA_COL] for row in islice(f, START_LINE, None)):

        if val != FAILED_MEASUREMENT:
            bt_values.append(float(val))

    min_bt = min(bt_values)
    max_bt = max(bt_values)

with open('minBt.txt', 'a') as minFile:
    print(min_bt, file=minFile)

with open('maxBt.txt', 'a') as maxFile:
    print(max_bt, file=maxFile)
```

I have assumed that since you are doing this to multiple files you are looking to accumulate multiple max and min values in the `maxBt.txt` and `minBt.txt` files, and hence I've opened them in 'append' mode. If this is not the case, please swap out the `'a'` argument for `'w'`, which will overwrite the file contents each time.

**Edit**: Updated to include workaround for failed measurements, as discussed in comments.

**Edit 2**: Updated to fix problem with negative numbers, also noted by Derek in separate answer.

Comment: Ok, next question if you don't mind please... Sometimes the sensor fails to take a measurement (and so the system that creates the file that I'm downloading instead enters -999.9 into that column. Is there a way of filtering out all values that equal -999.9 before searching for the min_bt value? Thanks again for your help. :)

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer to include a workaround for that. It only adds values from the column if they don't equal '-999.9'.

Comment: Thanks for the edit to your solution, Apoc. I had also just been able to find a slightly different solution, which I will share here in case someone else needs it, but I think your solution is more suitable for me specifically... here's what I found:

I put this immediately before your original solution:
`import fileinput, sys
for line in fileinput.input(filename, inplace=True):
    line = line.replace("-999.9", "")
    # sys.stdout is redirected to the file
    sys.stdout.write(line)`

Comment: Thanks again for your help, Apoc. :)

Comment: Ok. I need to do the same with the Bz column...:

`START_LINEbz = 20
DATA_COLbz = 9
FAILED_MEASUREMENTbz = '-999.9'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    bz_values = []
    for val in (row.split()[DATA_COLbz] for row in islice(f, START_LINEbz, None)):
        if val != FAILED_MEASUREMENTbz:
            bz_values.append(val)
    min_bz = min(bz_values)
    max_bz = max(bz_values)
#Write min and max Bz to files
with open('minBz.txt', 'w') as minFile:
    minFile.write(min_bz)
with open('maxBz.txt', 'w') as maxFile:
    maxFile.write(max_bz)`

(continued in next comment...)

Comment: ...used that last code in the same script as the earlier code you wrote up. It works ok except for the actual output to minBz.txt - for some reason it prints -0.1 to minBz.txt every time I run the script (despite the source file having values as low as -3.8).

Confusingly, it works perfectly fine for the maxBz though - it prints the correct max value to maxBz.txt.

Do you have any ideas why it might be doing that please? Thanks again and sorry for the hassles...

Comment: Yes you're right I'm sorry, previously this was calculating min-max based upon alphabetical ordering, which works fine for positive numbers but breaks for negative numbers. I've updated it to use floats as Derek pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is meant to be a comment on your latest question to Apoc, but I'm new, so I'm not allowed to comment. One thing that might create problems is that bz_values (and bt_values, for that matter) might be a list of strings (at least it was when I tried to run Apoc's script on the example file you linked to). You could solve this by substituting this:

```
min_bz = min([float(x) for x in bz_values]) 
max_bz = max([float(x) for x in bz_values])
```

for this:

```
min_bz = min(bz_values)
max_bz = max(bz_values)
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, Derek. I gave it a whirl, but was presented with the following error:

"    minFile.write(min_bz)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not float"

(for context, this is the line when we first try to write the min_bz value to the file)

`with open('/data examples/minBz.txt', 'w') as minFile:
    minFile.write(min_bz)`

(continued in the next comment...)

Comment: ...I also instead tried:

`    min_bz = min([str(x) for x in bz_values])
    max_bz = max([str(x) for x in bz_values])`

but that just printed -0.1 into the minBz file again.

Do you have any suggestions on how to fix the 'TypeError: write() argument must be str, not float' please? 
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You're completely right Derek, it was previously calculating min-max alphabetically (an oversight on my part). I've updated my answer to make it work with floats (and thus negative values). Also, the reason for the TypeError was that the `write` method only accepts strings, and both `min_bz` and `max_bz` are floats in your example. Rather than doing another type conversion I've switched to using the `print` function to avoid this.

Comment: Brilliant! That updated fix works perfectly. Thanks again to you both for your help. :)